# On hover closing specific list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<ul class="open-close1" id="reportType">
    <li class="active">
        <div id="subcats">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img class="loading-spinner" src="store/$vendorSettingsDTO.vendorId/assets/themes/$vendorSettingsDTO.skinname/images/loading.gif" height="18"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</li>
</ul>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery.getJSON('subcat.ajx?vid=$vendorSettingsDTO.vendorId&cid=$catid', function(data) {

       //Render subcatergories using Mustache.js (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

        var subcat_mustache =
            '<ul>\
            <a style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#0073B3;" class="opener"href="{{URL}}">{{description}}</a>\
            {{#childs}}\
            {{> child}}\
            {{/childs}}\
            </ul>';

        var partials = {
            child:
                '<li>\
                <a class="opener" href="{{URL}}">{{description}}</a>\
                <div class="subnav1 hidden">\
                <ul>\
                {{#childs}}\
                {{> child}}\
                {{/childs}}\
                </ul>\
                </div>\
                </li>'
            }
        jQuery("#subcats").html(Mustache.render(subcat_mustache, data, partials));
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".open-close1").hover(function (){
        //$(this).children('.subnav1').toggle();
        //console.log("$(this).children('.subnav1') "+$(this).children('.subnav1'));
        //$(".subnav1", this).toggle();
        $(this).find('.subnav1').toggle(); // p00f
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the code I have in case of my category page. I implemented a logic to toggle the block on hover. But entire list of categories is toggling instead of specific list on which it is hovered.

Please help me its IRRITATING me. Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: please provide the rendered html

Comment: First thing: your HTML is not well-formed, you close a non-open `<div>` element. This gets obvious as soon as you indent your code correctly.

Comment: Extra </div> was part of other block, removed the same to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your rendered html like below;

```
<ul class="open-close1" id="reportType">
    <li class="active"> 
           <div id="subcats">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="opener" href="#">Item1</a>
                        <div class="subnav1 hidden">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Item1-1</li>
                                <li>Item1-2</li>
                                <li>Item1-3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="opener" href="#">Item2</a>
                        <div class="subnav1 hidden">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Item2-1</li>
                                <li>Item2-2</li>
                                <li>Item2-3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="opener" href="#">Item3</a>
                        <div class="subnav1 hidden">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Item3-1</li>
                                <li>Item3-2</li>
                                <li>Item3-3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

You can use following js for above html structure;

```
$(".opener").hover(function (){
    $(this).next().toggle();               
});
```

Here is a working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/EKu2q/**

**Edit:** On your site, category section you mentioned loaded with ajax. So you need to run function after ajax load like below;

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery.getJSON('subcat.ajx?vid=$vendorSettingsDTO.vendorId&cid=$catid', function(data) {

       //Render subcatergories using Mustache.js (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

        var subcat_mustache =
            '<ul>\
            <a style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#0073B3;" class="opener"href="{{URL}}">{{description}}</a>\
            {{#childs}}\
            {{> child}}\
            {{/childs}}\
            </ul>';

        var partials = {
            child:
                '<li>\
                <a class="opener" href="{{URL}}">{{description}}</a>\
                <div class="subnav1 hidden">\
                <ul>\
                {{#childs}}\
                {{> child}}\
                {{/childs}}\
                </ul>\
                </div>\
                </li>'
            }
        jQuery("#subcats").html(Mustache.render(subcat_mustache, data, partials));

        $(".opener-parent").parent('li').hover(function (){
            $(this).find('subnav1').toggle();               
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I have also give class name for upper categories as `opener-parent` and updated js code

Updated demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/R9KLz/4/**

**Final Result:** If you do not want to add `opener-parent` class, you can use following;

```
$("#subcats ul li").hover(function (){
    if ($(this).find('.subnav1').first().find("ul").has("li").length) {
        $(this).find('.subnav1').first().toggle();
    }              
});
```

Here is a working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/R9KLz/5/**

Comment: Its perfectly working in the fiddle which you have shared, thanks a lot for this. But the same piece of code didn't work for me, my html structure is as below:

Comment: Where is your HTML? Add your html in your question, it would be better

Comment: But your html is corrupted I think, Have you got live site?

Comment: Your solution is perfectly working in fiddle as well, but not in my website. Its awesome. Awesome challenge.

Comment: @Santosh I edited your fiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/R9KLz/1/ . By the way, If you have live site, may I see it? Ican help better on live site

Comment: Yes Babal your solution is perfectly working in fiddle, see my previous comment. But not working in my site. http://dsqa.avetti.ca/preview/mystore15/side-bar/all-sports

Comment: On left side menu right? Whic part exactly working wrong? Menu is opena as start, when I hover, it collapses. How should it work?

Comment: Yes it is the left side menu. The menu is not at all opening for me. Are you on skype please? http://jsfiddle.net/santosh_NII_1989/R9KLz/

Comment: you can write your gmail, we can proceed over hangout.

Comment: santosh.anantharamaiah@decathlon.in I am looking for category              ALL SPORTS
CYCLING
HIKING
CLIMBING
RACQUET SPORTS
TEAM SPORTS
WATERSPORTS
ROLLER SPORTS
TARGET SPORTS
COMBAT SPORTS
FITNESS
RUNNING
NATURE SPORTS
HORSE RIDING
GOLF

Comment: I have invited you on gmail

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your request till now. Could you please post your mail id.

Comment: @Santosh You have another element with class `opener` see my edit on answer for your fix

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/santosh_NII_1989/R9KLz/3/ It is still not working for me in my website. And see in the updated fiddle, we have one more problem, we are unable to click on the sub categories right?

Comment: @Santosh my code was true, your above catogery fetched from ajax. So my code cannot work on document ready. Because, when document ready, your cats loaded with ajax. Put my code like in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Something I noticed, I think you have an extra `<div>` in your list markup.

```
<ul class="open-close1" id="reportType">
    <li class="active">
        <div id="subcats">
            <ul>
                <li><img class="loading-spinner" src="store/$vendorSettingsDTO.vendorId/assets/themes/$vendorSettingsDTO.skinname/images/loading.gif" height="18"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <!--</div>-->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also, I just a hunch, but I think you need to be more specific in which element inside of your class you want to talk to. For example, you have this:

```
$(this).find('.subnav1').toggle();
```

But I think you need something more along the lines of:

```
$(this).find('.subnav1 ul').toggle();
```

Or, if possible, you could give your list(s) some sort of hook to make it even easier to talk to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/santosh_NII_1989/R9KLz/ this is what I am trying to do. Its working fine in my fiddle, but not in my website http://dsqa.avetti.ca/preview/mystore15/side-bar/all-sports/cycling/cycles